# Can C++Builders clang32 compiler consume VS libraries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang++

I'm trying out the clang32 compiler coming with C++ builder 10.2. Builder don't yet have any good support for CMake, so a great number of 3rd party libraries are (very) hard to compile using it.

Anyone knowing if there is any binary compatibility between clang32 and Visual Studio compiler?

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially three different levels of compatibility you need to worry about:

1. File formats for object code and debug data, which allow you to use `clang` to build part of your project and Visual C++ `cl.exe` to build a library and then link them together and debug both.
2. Ability to write code and structure data that conforms to a portable binary interface, so it can be called across a mix of compilers.
3. Binary compatibility of the C++ standard library, so that standard library objects can be shared across a mix of compilers.

I can definitely say that (2) is supported and (3) absolutely is not; you can't even share standard library objects between different patchlevels of the same compiler.  For (1) I don't know.  A common way to bypass the issues with (1) is to build a DLL using each compiler, so they dynamically interface but no static linking nor merging of debug data is necessary.

If your concern is about `cmake` though, I think your problem is not the compiler (clang is available for Linux and `cmake` supports it well -- you should find the make scripts are capable of configuring all the compiler options).  Whether it can generate project files for C++Builder is a different story, but perhaps you should consider using a different IDE.  There are many with `clang` support, even Microsoft's Visual Studio has some ability to use `clang` for the compile step, and it's getting better with each release.